# How can I see the actual implementation code of different data structures in C++?

Tags: c++, list, vector, data-structures, set

Is there a way to look at the actual code which is used to implement different data structures like list, vector<>, unorderd_map<>, map, set in C++.

I was willing to see just how efficient these implementations are.

And I am surprised that Google has no reasonable result on this.

Thanks.

Comment: isn't (most of) them just inside headers?

Comment: Since these are templates, and in order to actually instantiate those templates their complete definition must be visible, you will be pleasantly surprised to find "the actual code" in your compiler's header files.

Comment: You can trust that these implementations are more efficient (and correct) than anything you or I will ever write. They are also usually completely and utterly unreadable even to long-time professionals, and are allowed to do things that are off limits to us mortals.

Comment: Be aware that standard library code is not written with the same requirements as user code. A specific standard library implementation will be written with a specific architecture or compiler in mind and may make optimizations that only make sense in that context. It can also rely on compiler extensions which allow it to be written in a way that is not portable and in some cases would otherwise be Undefined Behavior. Standard library implementations also use identifiers which are reserved for that purpose. In short, be selective about what you learn from standard library code.

Comment: Additionally, you can look at the "Possible implementation" section of the cppreference.com site. For example, here is `std::advance` [possible implementation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance#Possible_implementation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different implementations of the C++ standard, and some of them are open-source. For example, gcc's implementation is called libstdc++. The source code for `std::vector<T>`, for example, can be consulted here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/libstdc++/api/a01115_source.html

An interesting example of what you you can see in the file is that `std::vector<T>::push_back()` simply calls `std::vector<T>::emplace_back()`:

```
00370       template<typename _Up = _Tp>
00371         typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<!std::__are_same<_Up, bool>::__value,
00372                     void>::__type
00373         push_back(_Tp&& __x)
00374     { emplace_back(std::move(__x)); }
```

Comment: Microsoft's Standard Library implementation https://github.com/microsoft/STL

Comment: *"simply calls"* leave it to a standard implementation to make such a simple forwarding call so obfuscated. At least in this case I get why it's that way (`std::vector<bool>` and reserved identifiers) but it is always shocking to me to look at standard headers.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux True, one is always in for a surprise when consulting the standard headers.